# How to send a service via a binder to a fragment on API level 14?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-binder

I have made an Android app, on Android 4.4.4, and I want to develop it on Android 4.0.0. I have a problem to send a service, my binder, to a fragment.

On Android 4.4.4 I use the following lines :

```
AddTrashFragment addTrashFragment = new AddTrashFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap2);
bundle.putString("fileName", fileName);
bundle.putBinder("binder", binder);
addTrashFragment.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.relativeLayout,addTrashFragment).addToBackStack(null).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

But when I try to build my project with Android 4.0.0 I have the following error :
Call requires API level 18 (current min is 14): android.os.Bundle#putBinder less (Ctrl + F1)

I don't understand how to send my service, my binder, to a fragment when I try to build my project on Ice Scream Sandwich.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `Bundle.putBinder()` is API 18+ you'll have to do it a different way.  The simplest is to have your `Fragment` define a callback interface which your `Activity` must implement:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    MyFragment.Callback  cb;

    public interface Callback {
        Binder getServiceBinder();
    }
    ...

    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        try {
            cb = (MyFragment.Callback)context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Activity (Context) must implement Callback");
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyFragment.Callback {
    private Binder  mService;
    ...

    public Binder getServiceBinder() {
        return mService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is happening because `bundle.putBinder(Binder)` was added later on API 18 only. 
So, in devices with API 14, that code will fail since that method does not exist on those devices.

Maybe, you can create a public method in your Fragment and call it like:

```
public class AddTrashFragment extends Fragment {
    private Binder binder;

    public void setBinder(Binder binder) {
        this.binder = binder;
    }
}
```

And in your activity, you call:

```
AddTrashFragment addTrashFragment = new AddTrashFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap2);
bundle.putString("fileName", fileName);
addTrashFragment.setArguments(bundle);

addTrashFragment.setBinder(binder);
```

**OR**

You can get the Binder from activity like:

```
public class MainAcitivity extends Activity {
    public Binder getBinder() {
        return binder;
    }
}
```

and in your fragment:

```
public AddTrashFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Binder binder;
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if(activity != null && activity instanceof MainActivity)
            binder = ((MainAcitivity)activity).getBinder();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BundleCompat` to put and get an `IBinder` from a `Bundle`.

See: [BundleCompat Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/BundleCompat#putBinder(android.os.Bundle,%2520java.lang.String,%2520android.os.IBinder))